# How to find and replace a list of words with a list of words in textmate or with perl

Tags: perl, replace, textmate

I have a long list of words as follows

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
word7
```

I would like to do a find and replace on these words without individually finding a word. Id like to create a list of find targets and run this just once eg my target list would be as below.

```
word2
word4
word6
```

How can I do this and can it be done in textmate. Alternatives also considered obviously but I'm not familiar with perl scripts.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: it would be word2
word4
word6. Im just trying to find the targets in a list so I can then replace them individually with another word

Comment: `grep -f file2 file1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but it sounds like you want to create a regular expression from the second file and apply it to each line in the first. Something like (untested):

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, '<', $second_file;
chomp( my @lines = <$fh> );
close $fh;

my $joined = join( q{|}, map { quotemeta( $_ ) } @lines );
my $qr = qr{ $joined };

open $fh, '<', $first_file;
while( <$fh> ){
  if( /$qr/ ){
    print;
  }
}
close $fh;
```